# How to make a standalone scrollbar auto visible, dependent on the scrollviewer it controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer where my HorizontalScrollbarVisibility is hidden, because I want my actual scrollbar to be placed elsewhere in my UI.

Don't worry about best or bad practice, just trust me that this is the best way to show the scrollbar (one of the reasons is that I actually scroll 2 synchronized views, which works fine and is not part of the problem).

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
...
</ScrollViewer>
...
<ControlsWPF:BindableScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal" BoundScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=scrollView}"/>
```

The BindableScrollBar is just inherited from the normal wpf ScrollBar control, so consider it as such. 
(it comes from a great piece of code found here: [How to link scrollbar and scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330497/how-to-link-scrollbar-and-scrollviewer))

Now, my problem is that the standalone scrollbar is always visible. I would like it to behave as when setting *HorizontalScrollBarVisibility* to *auto* on the scrollviewer. It should only be visible if there is need for a scrollbar, else it should be collapsed.

If there is anyone who have an idea how to solve this, preferable in XAML only, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330497/how-to-link-scrollbar-and-scrollviewer

Comment: @GinoBambino, I think you misunderstand my question. That link is exactly the one I point to in my post. I have already been there, and done that, now I need the _visibility_ to be bound also.

Comment: What about simply binding the visibility of your scrollbar to the "ScrollBarVisibility"-property of the related scrollviewer? Would that be enough for you? You could write a simple value converter to convert the value of the ScrollBarVisibility to a corresponding value of Visibility.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the scrollviewers _ScrollbarVisibility_ will always be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Computed[Vertical|Horizontal]ScrollBarVisibility property on the ScrollViewer:

```
<ControlsWPF:BindableScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal" BoundScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=scrollView}" Visibility="{Binding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=scrollView}"/>
```

To actually remove scrollbars from the ScrollViewer you can remove the scrollbars from its style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NoBarsScrollViewerControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Another solution would be to compute it by your self but you will need to listen for plenty of ScrollViewer's event.

```
bool ScrollBarVisibility = ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth > ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I already looked at _ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility_. It doesn't work because the scrollviewers scrollbar is always hidden - that is why I am using a standalone scrollbar instead.

Comment: You could remove the ScrollBar from ScrollViewer's style and keep HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Auto. Another solution would be to compute it by your self but you will need to listen for plenty of ScrollViewer's events.

Comment: That actually sounds like a nice idea - to remove it from the style and bind as you originally suggested. I have never tried to change part of a controls ControlTemplate, do you by any change have any clue on how to approach this?

Comment: I added an exemple of a ScrollViewer template with no ScrollBars. Itis actually possible just to remove them and ScrollViewer will still work fine.