# WPF DataGrid content size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a `DataGrid` to external `ScrollBar`. To compute the `Thumb` size I need to know sizes of the grid and its viewport. Viewport can be accessed via `ActualWidth` in this case, but how can I access the width of the `DataGrid's` content (in code behind)? In XAML it is set to `Auto`, so it is `NaN` in code behind.

Digging into Visual Tree I've noticed, that `Grid` representing header (highlighted on the screenshot below)

[image: Grid with real width]

seemes to have the real width, I need. However, I am not sure neither how to access it, nor if it is an optimal way to achieve my goal.

How can I get the real width of `DataGrid`s  content, when it's set to `Auto` in XAML?

Comment: If there is already `ScrollBar` inside, then you only need to [find it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10279092/1997232) and bind its properties 1:1 to external `ScrollBar`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4330497/1997232).